# Why are the naming conventions for replacements different in stringr and forcats?

Tags: r, stringr, forcats

I have a hard time remembering the correct naming conventions for passing key-value pairs to `stringr::str_replace_all()` and `forcats::fct_recode()`. Apparently, both functions differ with respect to whether they need a vector of named strings or individual named strings and the order of the pairs:

```r
library("tidyverse")

ggplot2::diamonds %>%
  mutate(cut = stringr::str_replace_all(cut, 
                               c("Ideal" = "Awesome","
                                 Premium" = "Deluxe")))

ggplot2::diamonds %>%
  mutate(cut = forcats::fct_recode(cut, 
                          "Awesome" = "Ideal", 
                          "Deluxe" = "Premium"))
```

Knowing that both functions do different things, is there a reason that the naming conventions are different? Perhaps the conventions are just arbitrary--if not, I would like to understand the underlying logic.